# Mongoose: Property 'set' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

Hope you are having an amazing day, I'm having this issue with mongoose and typescript. Basically, I have a schema called joinGate. When a discord user runs a setup command, data should be added into the database. This is my code:

```
import { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose'; //https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html
import joinGateSchema, { JoinGateOptions } from '../../schemas/joingate';

const queryJoinGate: HydratedDocument<JoinGateOptions> = await joinGateSchema.findById(interaction.guild?.id);
    
if (queryJoinGate) {

    queryJoinGate.set({
        _id: interaction.guild?.id,
        inviteRoles: [args]
    });
    queryJoinGate.save();
    // update the existing data

} else {

    queryJoinGate.set({
    //^Property 'set' does not exist on type 'never'.
        _id: interaction.guild?.id,
        inviteRoles: [args]
    });
    queryJoinGate.save();
    //^Property 'save' does not exist on type 'never'.

}
```

I'm not sure why I get the Property 'set' does not exist on type errors, but basically I need to add some different data into the database if no data exists. I'm unable to do that with these two errors.  Any help is appreciated, thanks so much!

Comment: You can use `.findOne()` to look for an existing data, if non. You can do `new queryJoinGate({})`

Comment: Thanks! It looks like new queryJoinGate({...}) works the best.

Comment: Do you know how to look for existing? Or Should I provide some hint code?

Comment: I got it thanks! I was just having some issues with that part XD